# Calculate size of JSON Data Endpoint?

Tags: download

I am making a call to an endpoint that returns JSON. When I save the data to a file, the total size is 500 Kilobytes. What I wanted to do was to compress the JSON, but I heard by just enabling compression on the web server (Apache), I will accomplish the same thing. Now I have done that, and enabled compression. But how do I get the size of the DOWNLOAD, and not the size of the file if I save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite as simple as just enabling compression on the web server. The HTTP request received by the server must include the `Accept-Encoding` header to indicate which compression scheme or schemes it support.

The most common is: `Accept-Encoding: gzip`.

You'd likely need to use a packet sniffer (fiddler or equivalent) to determine the difference in payload sizes when compressed versus decompressed. Most HTTP libraries I am aware of decompress the payload before passing it back to the calling code.

Comment: So would it perhaps be better to compress the JSON and then uncompress it in the app?

Comment: Definitely not, IMHO! Most implementations of the HTTP protocol (e.g .NET, Java, Python, Swift, etc) support compression at the library level. Just make sure to enable it. If the HTTP library you're using doesn't support compression, consider implementing it in that open-source project, not your private code base. Compression support happens at the Server level, but the server's use of compression is based on the Request's header content.